# Openlayer zoomify dependency

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I need a little help about the zoomify. 
I want to display big images, everything is working, but I don't want to include all openlayer Javascript files which Javascript do I need there.

All the best, 
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLayers has special tools to help us with our deployments. You can use them to build a personal OpenLayers file that has only and exactly what you need.

The link is here: http://docs.openlayers.org/library/deploying.html (read section 'Custom Build Profiles')

Answer (score 0):

After downloading openlayer, in the directory build you will find different config file. You can make your own. For example in order to use only zoomify, this one should work.

```
[first]

[last]

[include]
OpenLayers/Map.js
OpenLayers/Layer/Zoomify.js
OpenLayers/Layer/Markers.js
OpenLayers/Layer/Boxes.js
OpenLayers/Marker/Box.js
OpenLayers/Control/Navigation.js
OpenLayers/Control/Zoom.js
OpenLayers/Protocol/HTTP.js
OpenLayers/Strategy/Fixed.js
OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX.js
OpenLayers/StyleMap.js
OpenLayers/Rule.js
OpenLayers/Filter/Comparison.js
OpenLayers/Filter/Logical.js
[exclude]
```

Build the custom openlayer.js with python

```
python build.py mycustomconfig.cfg
```